# bootstrap date-picker paste control

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Even I set forceParse option to false, when I paste a text into the input box, it auto set to today.

For typing, I can type in any letters, but for the pasting (ctrl + v) is not working, if the pasting text is not in the correct format then.

How can I disable(ignore) the paste auto-collect action so that I can paste any letter into the input box? I do formatting manually when blurring from the input box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('#yourcalenderid').datepicker({
    forceParse: false
 });
```

http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#forceparse

As commented, in bootstrap-datepicker.js line 508 change it to the following

```
paste: function(e){
    /* var dateString;
     if (e.originalEvent.clipboardData && e.originalEvent.clipboardData.types
        && $.inArray('text/plain', e.originalEvent.clipboardData.types) !== -1) {
        dateString = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    } else 
    if (window.clipboardData) {
        dateString = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
    } else {
        return;
    }
    this.setDate(dateString);
    this.update();
    e.preventDefault(); */
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but still it does auto correcting

Comment: oh, sry got your question wrong. I have amended my answer

Comment: Yes, even I set forceParse to false. https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on#sandbox Could you please test on this? paste '5/11' into the input box, then it will auto correct the date to today, even you un-checked on Force parse option.

Comment: The link you gave is not working still, did you copy '5/11' and paste it? using ctrl+c and ctrl+v?

Comment: The paste event in datepicker.js has been builtin that it will prase the text when you trigger it. see bootstrap-datepicker.js on line 508.  In order to achieve the feature you want, you will need to modify that code